# Look for several characters in a string and get back an array of characters that are in the string?

Tags: php

Say I have the string:

```
$s = "ABCDEFGEHIJ";
```

and an array:

```
$a = array("2", "7", "A", "E", "J", "W", "Z");
```

How can I search $s to see if the characters in $a exist, then return an array with all characters that do? So I would get the result:

```
$result = array("A", "E", "J");
```

I've tried strpos($s, "A"); but this only works for a single string and returns the position so it doesn't fulfill the criteria. How would SO do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could loop. It seems a bit clunky to me though.

```
$s = "ABCDEFGEHIJ";
$a = array("2", "7", "A", "E", "J", "W", "Z");
$matches = array();
foreach ($a as $i) {
    if (strpos($i, $s)) {
        $matches[] = $i;
    }
}
```

Alternately regexp replace for everything not in the array of characters:

```
$s = "ABCDEFGEHIJ";
$a = array("2", "7", "A", "E", "J", "W", "Z");
$out = preg_replace('/[^' . implode('',$a) . ']/' , '', $s);
```

And turn that into an array with `str_split($out)`

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of doing that too. But I was wondering if there was a function that could already do this. Or perhaps a more elegant solution that I'm overlooking.

Comment: Added a regexp version!

Comment: I hadn't thought of the preg_replace solution. That's quite clever. :)